# Django how to adding comments option on a post

Tags: html, django

I am developing a blog which i want to add comment form option to it, i have added the form to the same page directly under the article, i want that went a user comment it should redirect to the same page with the article but i keep getting and error
here is my code 
view

```
def comment(request, article_id):
try:
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            article.comments_set.create(comment=comment)
            #messages.infos(request,comment)
            return redirect('blog:_article')
    #else:
        #pass
        #form = CommentForm()
        #context['form'] = form
    #return render(request,'blog/comment.html', context)
except Exception as e:
    #wriet error to file
    return render(request,'blog/404.html')
```

urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views




app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('<int:article_id>/article', views._article, name='_article'),
path('<int:article_id>/comment', views.comment, name='comment'),
```

]

models

```
class Comments(models.Model):
comment = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.comment
```

form

```
           <form method="post" action="{% url 'blog:comment' article.id %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                 {{ field.label_tag }}
                 {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" rows="4" %}
                {% endfor %}<br>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Post</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: This instead redirects to the url in the form action  url 'blog:comment' article.id

Answer (score 2):

I finally did it by adding the code to handle the comment in the same view that renders the articles this is my code

```
def _article(request, article_id):
try:
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=article_id)
    related_articles = Article.objects.filter(tags=article.tags).exclude(pk=article.pk)[:4]
    context['article'] = article
    context['related_articles'] = related_articles
    context['form'] = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            article.comments_set.create(comment=comment)
    return render(request,'blog/article.html', context)
except Exception as e:
    #write error to file
    return render(request,'blog/404.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the page to redirect to another page or update the page, you should use AJAX (https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) in this case. Your form will hit the url in the action by changing your page to that url so you have to handle the redirecting and rendering in your commenting view to come back to same page if you don't wanna do this dynamically.

Comment: i want it to redirect to the same page

Comment: Then you should go to your view function `views.comment` and add redirect to the end like `return redirect('blog:_article')` so it comes back to the article after the post.